# Is a good practice to throw memory error back to client

Tags: java, exception, throttling

I have a UI being developed in HTML5 and angular JS , which makes a webservice call to REST endpoint developed in Java ,

As our REST endpoint is accepting a file so we have throttled the file request so as accept only given amount of file request from the client .

Now if the threshold is reached my question is it a good design to throw error back to client say "memory threshold reached" back to client or Do i send some generic error back to client as the consumer of this end point is other consumers as well from different clients

Comment: This is largely opinion-based, but fwiw, if there's no security leak from them knowing the reason for the failure, and the reason is something they can take actionable steps on (maybe compress images more than they otherwise would?) then I would give them that information.

Comment: Isn't http 429 what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The way we currently handle this in our application is to actually do a client side check on the file first, before even making the REST call.  Should the file selected exceed the threshold size which the API can tolerate, then we give an appropriate error message right there to this effect.

With this check in place, the only way that a file too large to be handled could be uploaded would be if a given user were to somehow hack around the UI, or if someone were using a really old or non supported browser.  Both of these are probably rare cases, so any generic error message stating the REST call failed should be sufficient.

Here is a link to a tutorial which covers the HTML 5 file API: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

It is possible to capture a local file's size directly in your JavaScript code.  This information can then be used to display a message, block an upload, etc. depending on how you want to handle the size.  Note that you cannot get the file's local path on the computer, because that would be a security problem.